# ERROR in node_modules/@types/pdfjs-dist/index.d.ts(63,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'. for Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am new in Angular.

I have error "ERROR in node_modules/@types/pdfjs-dist/index.d.ts(63,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'." when using `npm run ng serve`

My package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.2.3",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  }
```

My package-lock.json

```
"pdfjs-dist": {
  "version": "2.3.200",
  "resolved": "****",
  "integrity": "****",
  "requires": {
    "node-ensure": "^0.0.0",
    "worker-loader": "^2.0.0"
  }
},
"@types/pdfjs-dist": {
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "resolved": "***",
  "integrity": "***"
},
```

but I keep have error of `"ERROR in node_modules/@types/pdfjs-dist/index.d.ts(63,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'."`

Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: try installing the dependencies again using `npm install` and then run `ng serve`

Comment: @Ramesh hi, I have tried to delete node_modules and `npm install` and try using `ng serve`. But it still keeps popup this error.

Comment: There are some questions on this error in StackOverflow look through them. [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624698/error-in-node-modules-types-pdfjs-dist-index-d-ts63-39-error-ts2304-cannot)

Comment: @Ramesh I have followed this question. But this seem not work for me. I still have this error.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I would say this is a TypeScript version issue, but the `unknown` type had not been introduced into TypeScript until version number 3.

Release notes: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type

But what I do notice is that your `@types/pdfjs-dist` does contain the `unknown` type in its source files, so it might be that those types are not allowed with the version of TypeScript that you are using.

Source file: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pdfjs-dist/index.d.ts

Also the `peerDependency` of this lib (v5.2.3) on the types file is: ["@types/pdfjs-dist": "^0.1.2"](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/blob/5.2.3/package.json). You are using a way higher version (v2.1.0), so I think this the main reason for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

On my case, the problem is on the @types/pdfjs-dist/index.d.ts.

I have downloaded from npm but there are keyword `unknown` in line 63. it displays on other lines also. just delete the method is fine.